# Can I make left Alt act the same as shift key using key map?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, keyboard-layout

I would like to swap my left <kbd>shift</kbd> key with my left <kbd>alt</kbd> key, and I would like to know if it’s possible to achieve this with vim key mapping.

Maybe not swapping but copy the whole <kbd>shift</kbd> key map to <kbd>alt</kbd>?

Comment: You can't really do that in Vim, there's a limited version of that you *could* do with much work... But you're definitely better off by looking at remapping keys on your OS's keyboard driver, where you can easily accomplish something exactly like that and it would work on any application you use. I suggest you ask in Superuser (or Ask Different if on a Mac) about how to remap those keys in your OS.

Answer (score 1):

In vim, nvi, vi, and so forth (all of the terminal vi clones, to be precise), no.  A terminal session doesn't transmit the modifier key presses separate from the keys they're modifying.  It's true that terminal emulators have come a long way since when they were first made, and they have a lot more capabilities now.  But that's something that's pretty fundamental to the data flow on how old terminals worked, and I don't see it as something that would be possible to change without breaking compatibility with all sorts of things they're supposed to be compatible with.

I've checked to see if there's a gvim capability to do this.  As of 8.2, based on my reading of `:help :map`, especially the section `:help :map-alt-keys`, there does not appear to be.  gvim *does* recognize the modifier keys itself, but it appears to fundamentally not make a distinction between the left or right modifier key of any set that has a pair, and it fundamentally doesn't recognize the modifier key presses except when there's also a non-modifier key pressed.

The only things that would stop you from doing a full list of

```
:noremap <A-A> <A-a>
:noremap <A-a> <A-A>
:norelmap <A-A> <A-a>
:norelmap <A-a> <A-A>
:noremap <A-B> <A-b>
:noremap <A-b> <A-B>
:norelmap <A-B> <A-b>
:norelmap <A-b> <A-B>
...
```

would be your patience with going through all of them and the confusion factor from the amount that you've already gotten used to them being the thing they are by default.  I don't know of a way to get a listing of all of the keycodes that actually *do* something, so there's no way I know of to be thorough for all the keys that matter but not bother with the ones that don't.

Of course, simply mapping the shifted alt keys to the unshifted alt keys would cause you to lose access to the shifted alt keys' functions, unless you mapped something *else* to get there.

Note that I'm using the `:noremap` command there because a simple `:map` both directions like that would result in an infinite loop.  I'm using both `:noremap` and `:norelmap` because you didn't indicate what contexts you want the remap to happen, and that's the simplest way to get virtually all contexts.

There's a table of map commands at `:help map-modes`, which was very confusing to me when I first started using vim, but it should be helpful to you here.  My confusion was because the three columns of commands aren't marked.  The first column is recursive mappings (that is, after the key press is translated, the new code gets looked up to see if it gets mapped in some way, too), the second column is non-recursive mappings (what I naturally expected from map commands), and the third is how to undo either type of mapping.

---

That having been said, if you have access to your OS keyboard layout, you can do that sort of change.  The simplest way would make that change for everything on the system.  The details of how to do that would probably be under either an OS specific SE, or Super User SE.

Comment: Then can I access the whole vim key map file and change all shift to alt?

Comment: @Andrew.Wolphoe wdym? What vim key map file?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Maybe like using vim script and first list out all key bond start with shift then remap them to alt key. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Is this close to what you want?

```
let s:str='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
for i in range(len(s:str))
    let s:c=s:str[i]
    exe 'map <A-'.s:c.'> <S-'.s:c.'>'
    exe 'lmap <A-'.s:c.'> <S-'.s:c.'>'
    exe 'tmap <A-'.s:c.'> <S-'.s:c.'>'
endfor
```

where `s:` specify the scope of the variables (see `:help s:`) and command `exe` executes the string following it. `.`  concatenates strings together. For example, if `i` is 3, then `s:c` becomes `d`, and `map <A-d> <S-d>` will be executed.